# how can i grab the last value of a coloumn

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables

```
1.course(c_id(pk),c_name,sem_no);
2.student(s_id(pk),s_name,user_name,password);
3.student_info(s_id(fk),c_id(fk));
```

I have logged in the student, THEN i run this query

`SELECT distinct sem_no FROM course,student_info WHERE course.c_id=student_info.c_id and s_id='0001' ORDER BY sem_no ;`

It shows all the semester he passed including the running semester..
now

I want to show the last value of `sem_no` column as his current semester..
how can I grab the last value of the `sem_no`?

**Any help will be appreciated!**

Comment: Invert the order and limit the result set to one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
 SELECT sem_no
    FROM course  as t1 join
         student_info as t2
         on t1.c_id = t2.c_id 
    WHERE t2.s_id = '0001'
    ORDER BY sem_no desc
    LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an improved version of what you want:

```
SELECT sem_no
FROM course c join
     student_info si
     on c.c_id = si.c_id and s_id = '0001'
ORDER BY sem_no desc
LIMIT 1;
```

Note the use of proper ANSI join syntax.  Also notice the use of table aliases, which make the query easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

When selecting from mysql, you can order by either ascending or descending. ascending would be from 1-10 eg. and descending would be 10-1. So

`SELECT distinct sem_no FROM course.student_info 
 WHERE course.c_id=student_info.c_id and s_id='0001' ORDER BY sem_no desc LIMIT 1;`

would return last row, and only last row.